# ImageField и путь к изображениям

Tags: python, django

Моя модель содержит поле `ImageField`:

```py
from django.db import models
class Card(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField('Фото профиля', upload_to = "pictures/about/photos/", max_length = 100, null = True)
```

Настройки settings.py:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '' # пробовал '/' - вызывается [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/pictures'
MEDIA_URL = 'static/media/'
```

Изображения из поля ImageField помещаются в папку `static/media/` внутри проекта, но для статических файлов у меня используется папка, которая находится вне проекта. Структура выглядит примерно так:

```py
public_html
    main_project # директория с проектом
        dj # директория приложения-проекта
            settings.py
            ...
        about # директория приложения, в котором и находится моя модель
            models.py
            ...
        manage.py
    web # директория для раздачи файлов
        static
        media
```

При выгрузке файлов через админпанель в поле `ImageField` они загружаются в `public_html/main_project/pictures/about/photos`, т.е. путь, который был указан в  `upload_to` применяется именно относительно папки с проектом. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы фотографии выгружались в `public_html/web/pictures/about/photos`, или хотя бы в `public_html/web/media/pictures/about/photos`? Указывать абсолютный путь в модели ImageField нельзя, а переход на уровень выше через `../` вызывает исключение.

#### P.s.

`/static/` находится вне директории проекта, где он мне и нужен. Суть вопроса в том, можно ли сделать так, чтобы медиафайлы тоже находились вне директории проекта?

Answer (score 0):

я решил эту проблему так ,как показано в
https://github.com/yourlabs/django-documents/blob/master/documents/models.py

Comment: не могли бы Вы дать более подробное описание решения в своем ответе?